# can an Elastic Beanstalk load balancer URL be re-used?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

If I create an Elastic Beanstalk, it creates an Elastic Load Balancer with a URL like awseb-e-d-awsebloa-abcdeabcdeabc-000000000.ap-southeast-4.elb.amazonaws.com

Once I've deleted an Elastic Beanstalk, is there any possibility that the URL will be re-used? I know that you can't specify the load balancer URL when starting an Elastic Beanstalk, but if I create instances in bulk, is there a possibility that a new Elastic Beanstalk might create a load balancer with the URL awseb-e-d-awsebloa-abcdeabcdeabc-000000000.ap-southeast-4.elb.amazonaws.com again?

Answer (score 1):

Each EB environment will generate a new load balancer with unique URL and does not reuse or assign the same URL to multiple load balancers. This is built by design to ensure proper routing and isolation. Therefore, if an EB environment gets terminated, there's no possibility that a new EB environment will with the same URL.

If you want to keep the EB URL for DNS related concerns, consider looking at [environment swapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/blue-green-deployments/swap-the-environment-of-an-elastic-beanstalk-application.html) or just [associate your personal domains](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html) to your environments via `CNAME`.